# How do I install an older version of Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

The documentation explains how to install the newest version, but I need a specific (older) version. Could someone help me with the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6):

The official deb & rpm repositories don't provide the previous Crystal releases. We know we want to improve that at some point in time, but it's not happening yet.

If you're on macOS/using Homebrew, you can try [installing a Homebrew formula's old version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/641451). There *might* be a similar procedure in Linuxbrew. And I'm not sure about Arch's situation.

[Official Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/crystallang/crystal/tags/) go as far as 0.13, in case that helps.

And you can always [install Crystal from a .tar.gz](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/installation/from_a_targz.html) published on [the repository's Releases page](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/releases). Just pick the version you prefer instead of the latest.

Don't forget that, the older the Crystal version, the less supported it'll be.

Comment: On the releases page you can also find various `.deb`, `.rpm` and `.pkg` packages.